# Count of boolean column compared to first and last values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a table like this:

product_history

| fk_product_id | product_name (varchar) | product_name_changed (bit) | product_cost (int) | product_cost_changed (bit) | timestamp (datetime) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 284 | Product X | false | 100 | false | 08/04/2022 10am |
| 285 | Product Y | false | 20 | false | 08/06/2022 1pm |
| 285 | Product Y-2 | true | 20 | false | 08/07/2022 7am |
| 285 | Product Y | true | 20 | false | 08/07/2022 8am |
| 284 | Product X-2 | true | 100 | false | 08/07/2022 1pm |
| 284 | Product X-3 | true | 500 | true | 08/07/2022 3pm |
| 286 | Product Z | false | 4 | false | 08/08/2022 11am |
| 286 | Product Z | false | 8 | true | 08/08/2022 4pm |
| 286 | Product Z-2 | true | 8 | true | 08/09/2022 2pm |

This is basically a copy of a row in a product table, with a boolean column to show what columns were changed in this edit history. Now the customer wants to query this data for all values between a date range. Here's an example of how they want the results to look for something like a query between 08/07/2022 6am to 08/08/2022 10pm

| fk_product_id | product_name_count | product_cost_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 284 | 2 | 1 |
| 285 | 0 | 0 |
| 286 | 0 | 1 |

Essentially, they want to count all changes (true values in the changed columns) that occur per ID in the given time period. This is fairly easy, my approach on that is to do something like this:

```
count(CASE WHEN product_name_changed THEN 1 END) AS product_name_count,
```

in a select, where it's within the range and with GROUP BY fk_product_id.

### The Question

The tricky part here is the edge case they want. If, the last entry in the date range for that product ID has the same value as the *first entry in the entire table* for that product ID, then the [column]_count should be 0. Basically, if the change has been reverted to be equal to the first value, then that should show that no changes have been done in the time period on that column.

In my example, Product Y has it's name changed and reverted. As such, in the output, it's row has a 0 in product_name_count despite there being multiple "true" values in the product_name_changed column for that id. This occurs even though the first Product Y entry is outside the date range.

### What I've tried

I've been searching a lot for this. I tried adding something like

```
last_value(product_name) over (
    PARTITION BY fk_product_id]
    ORDER BY timestamp) AS product_name,
```

in order to store the last value and then use that in the logic for the count, but I'm not sure how to do that *and* get the first_value (including outside of the date range) to do the comparison.

And at this point I might try to make this two procedures and do the logic outside of SQL. However, since it was requested I try to do it in one go, I wanted to ask here and see if anybody could help at all.

Comment: Try and stick to useful facts that help us to assist you with the problem. The history of why and your experience just adds clutter. You want a [mre] with emphasis on minimal to make it clearer and easier to understand. And calling it complicated is pointless, because its only complicated relative to experience. So might be complex for some people, and not for others.

Comment: "has the same value as the first entry in the entire table for that product ID" i.e. this could be before the start of the requested date range?

Comment: Correct, it could be out of the range. The one it's compared to, the last value, is within the range however.

Comment: You can just use a subquery to get the starting value.

Comment: And thanks for the edits, I definitely overdid it trying to explain.

Comment: What would a subquery like that look like? I'm not sure how to do that per product_id and then use the resulting value in query

Comment: Can you have a go... I don't have time to write it all out right now. Google correlated sub-query.

Comment: Sure can, thanks for the tip

Comment: You might need to consider a few more complicated cases to make sure the results are what your customer wants. For example, If the product name changes from A > B > C > B, Should you treat the last as a reversal, but still count the A > B as a single change? If the price changes 10 > 20 > 30 > 10 > 40, should the 20 and 30 values be eliminated and the price changes counted as if the price sequence were 10 > 40? Just pointing out that the definition of what constitutes aa reverted value may be ambiguous in some scenarios without an explicit reverted indicator,

Comment: I mentioned some of these, however they didn't want to invest in a more complicated tracking of changes. They were content to only define a reversal as the most recent change in the dataset being equal to the first entry. It's a little odd, but that's what they settled on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be as follows

```
DECLARE @StartTime datetime = '2022-08-07 06:00:00.000', 
        @EndTime datetime = '2022-08-08 22:00:00.000';


WITH T AS
(
SELECT fk_product_id,       
       first_value(product_name) over (PARTITION BY fk_product_id ORDER BY timestamp) AS first_product_name, 
       first_value(product_cost) over (PARTITION BY fk_product_id ORDER BY timestamp) AS first_product_cost, 
       first_value(product_name) over (PARTITION BY fk_product_id ORDER BY timestamp desc) AS last_product_name,
       first_value(product_cost) over (PARTITION BY fk_product_id ORDER BY timestamp desc) AS last_product_cost,
       CAST(product_name_changed AS INT) AS product_name_changed,
       CAST(product_cost_changed AS INT) AS product_cost_changed,
       CASE WHEN timestamp >= @StartTime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS in_time_period
FROM product_history
WHERE timestamp <= @EndTime 
)
SELECT fk_product_id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN in_time_period = 1 AND first_product_name <> last_product_name THEN product_name_changed ELSE 0 END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN in_time_period = 1 AND first_product_cost <> last_product_cost THEN product_cost_changed ELSE 0 END)
FROM T
GROUP BY fk_product_id
HAVING SUM(in_time_period) > 0
```

The where clause is on `timestamp <= @EndTime` so the earliest values are available to the window functions but then there is additional logic added to only count the "changed" events if they fall inside the start/end window of interest and if the overall first value <> the overall last value.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d88afc5c9f484dc76053e6f200e69996)

NB1: I just use `first_value` and descending order rather than `last_value`. If you use `last_value` you need to also include  `UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` for it to work as you were wanting.

NB2: I also order the columns using the same window frames next to each other. This at least used to prevent some gratuitous sort operations compared to having frames intermingled. I haven't checked recently if this is still the case.

Comment: This looks like it might be exactly what I want. I'll try and implement this on my test database and report back how it works out.

Comment: This worked beautifully, thank you!